# AngularJS Data Binding Breaks ngRepeat + Strange Behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background**: I'm a systems guy who switched to Front End development. Just dorking around with Angular. Got creative with data binding and now I'm trying to understand this behavior:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div class="container">Name
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
    </div>{{ user.name }}
    <div class="container">Name
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
    </div>
    <ul ng-model="user.name">
        <li ng-repeat="l in user.name">{{ l }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpm74dd8/

I would expect this to take my input from either box, mirror the text between the input boxes, and repeat each letter on its own line at the bottom.

If I type "test" in one of the inputs, ng-repeat will break when a letter repeats.

Typing the alphabet sequentially works as I expect.

Why does ng-repeat break when input letters are duplicated? I have no practical use for this, I was just experimenting with Angular for fun and came across this and don't understand it.

Comment: `ng-repeat` works with a collection, for example an array. Not a string

Comment: Isn't a String just an array of characters?

Comment: no it is not an array, and can't be treated as one

Comment: Interesting. I see the track by $index below and it works. 

When I use "l in user.name.split()" it keeps the ul on the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-repeat will not accept duplicate entries. As `test` has `t` as duplicate entry, it will fail.

Add `track by` expression to avoid this.

When we do not provide any `track by` expression the entry(in this case each letter) itself is treated as a unique identifier to link the entry to the list to track the changes in it.

`<li ng-repeat="l in user.name track by $index">{{ l }}</li>`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did not understand that. Docs I was led to from your answer:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Use`track by $index` with ng-repeat for dupilcate entries in array. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1Lw11bqr/